# my c++ code does not let me input all input values, and i don't know why

Tags: c++

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    for (int j = 0; j < t; j++) {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        vector<string> cities;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cin >> cities[i];
        }
        int size = cities.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int k = 1; k < n; k++) {
                if (cities[i] == cities[k]) size--;
            }
        } 
        cout << size << '\n';
    }
    
}
```

So, this task is from kattis website(link: https://open.kattis.com/problems/everywhere) and the goal is to get the number of the cities someone has visited, the problem is that some of these cities were visited twice or even more, so the only thing we need is to get the number of cities.

That's how input looks like:

```
7
saskatoon
toronto
winnipeg
toronto
vancouver
saskatoon
toronto
3
edmonton
edmonton
edmonton
```

And my code doesn't let me input the whole input, I mean, I input 3 values and then program stops working. Can you help me?

Comment: Do you know the cause of the stop? Does it crash or simply finish?

Comment: Your vector has size zero, but you treat it as if it didn't. Vectors don't grow just because you assign to them. Use `push_back` to add strings to the vector.

Comment: oh, yeah thanks that's true

Comment: @john i've solved that issue, but that does not seem to help

Comment: @ShaneWalsh Well you need to post the new code and describe the new problem.

Comment: Best if you make a new question. If you make wholesale modifications to this one, you'll invalidate existing correct answers. Bad form, that.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to initialize your vector with a size. You can do it by passing `n` to the constructor:

```
vector<string> cities(n);
```

Comment: does vector need a size initialization?

Comment: @ShaneWalsh No. But if you know what the size will be beforehand (which in this case, we do) you can give it an initial size through the constructor. If your vector has no size, you can't access an element through `cities[i]` because that slot hasn't been allocated yet.

Comment: This does not answer the question nor solve the problem which he described.
This is also only relevant when one deals with a lot of data

Comment: @FinnEggers Well, he has undefined behavior for doing `cities[i]` before space has been allocated for that index, so fixing that issue could be the solution.

Comment: Well then ideally he should use .reserve() or even .resize()

Comment: But you are right here. Sorry my bad! Didnt see that this was causing it

Comment: @FinnEggers reserve would not help, resize might. The problem is that the vector has size zero, so `cities[i]` is incorrect

Comment: still, that does not help

Comment: @ShaneWalsh Are you experiencing the same issue?

Comment: Assuming you have only one bug slows down the debugging process. You will often fix a bug and find the program behaves even worse because it can now get further.